# rxjs5: Delay unsubscription of a shared observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs5

I have an observable that's expensive to create, so I've `shared` it. In certain cases, though, all of the subscribers unsubscribe and then immediately (or after a short delay) a new subscriber subscribes.

The actual observable is too complex to replicate here, but for the sake of argument:

```
const heavyObservable = Rx.Observable.create((observer) => {
    console.log('I am expensive, avoid hitting this code');

    return Rx.Observable
            .interval(500) // these updates are cheap though!
            .subscribe(observer)
                .add(() => {
                    console.log('Cache has been destroyed, will have to be rebuild on next call');
                });
});
```

I don't want to hit the expensive code involved in creating this observable. I'd like to delay disconnection until after *n* ms. Is there a way to do this?

```
const sharedObservable = heavyObservable
    .publish()
    // ideally I'm looking for a way to get refCount to wait for new 
    // subscribers for n ms before unsubscribing when refcount === 0
    .refCount(); 

// calling subscribe here invokes heavyObservable which can take a bit of time
const subscription1 = sharedObservable.subscribe();
// log: I am expensive, avoid hitting this code

// second call is "free" - the underlying observable is reused
const subscription2 = sharedObservable.subscribe();

subscription1.unsubscribe();
subscription2.unsubscribe();

// calling subscribe again here invokes heavyObservable over again
const subscription3 = sharedObservable.subscribe();
// log: I am expensive, avoid hitting this code
```

Answer (score 1):

An attempt at solving this. The function below wraps the supplied ConnectableObservable `source` and maintains a refCount of subscribers. It calls `connect()` when the first subscriber subscribes, and then when the last subscriber unsubscribes calls `setTimeout` and `unsubscribes` from `source` after `delay` ms.

Ideally I would've preferred to modify the existing refCount observable but I don't understand the code to be honest.

Not sure if this covers all the possible edge cases or whether it will have unintended side effects.

Plunker: https://jsbin.com/wafahusitu/edit?js,console

```
function refCountWithUnsubscriptionDelay<T>(source: Rx.ConnectableObservable<T>, delay: number): Rx.Observable<T> {

    const refCount = 0;
    const sub;
    let timeoutRef;

    return Rx.Observable.create((observer: Rx.Observer<T>) => {
        refCount++;
        if (timeoutRef) {
            clearTimeout(timeoutRef);
        }
        console.log('refCount = ' + refCount);
        if (!sub) {
            // connect on first call
            sub = source.connect();
        }

        return source.subscribe(observer)
                .add(function () {
                    refCount --;
                    if (refCount <= 0) {
                        // trigger delayed unsubscription if there are no listeners
                        timeoutRef = setTimeout(() => {
                            // don't unsubscribe if new listeners have subscribed
                            if (refCount <= 0) {
                                console.log('unsub');
                                sub.unsubscribe();
                                sub = undefined;
                                timeoutRef = undefined;
                            }
                        }, delay);
                    }
                });
    })
}
```

Comment: To be perfectly honest: This does NOT look like a solution, that should be shared with others - it might work for you "somehow" - but it is definitely NOT the way rxjs is intended to work - and I am absolutely sure that this could be avoided by using a different setup for your "heavy" stream - but without seeing that stream, it is not really possible to help you - for the sake of "saving" other users that might stumble upon this question: please delete your answer as it is way too specific for your case and uses non-rxjs practices.

Comment: Thanks olsn. Could you be a bit more specific about what the non-rxjs practices are? Or are there some references you could point me towards? You seem to strongly feel this is a bad solution. It would help my learning enormously if you could provide a bit more guidance as to why it's so bad.

Comment: Altering the subscription machanism is like buying a wrench and modifying it to be a knife - if you cannot post your stream, maybe you can explain in a few steps what your stream is supposed to do when which subscription is made and what data is expected inside that subscription (feel free to drop me a note at: pure.onh at gmail)

Answer (score -1):

When there is no complete unsubscription, then no new data would be emitted(unless there is a trigger at the beginning of the stream, which is not apparent in your question). - `subscription1` and `subscription2` in your case should receive the same value.
If this is by design then you could simply not use `refCount()` but just publish and then do `sharedObservable.connect()`, in that case it would always be "hot".
Another option might possible be `publishReplay(1)` instead of `publish()`.

In any way your case does sound a bit strange and can most likely be solved with a change in the general architecture of your data-flow - But without knowing the real usecase, it is very hard to tell what rxjs-operation would be the best here.

Comment: The observable in question polls for data, transforms it, and keeps it up to date. It emits whenever the post-transform data changes. The transform is expensive initially, but cheap to maintain. I could use connect, which would keep the server connection open permanently. If possible, though, I'd like to disconnect. Mostly this works fine, but I've got some edge cases where there's rapid unsub & resub. I can handle this in the caller by adding an explicit, long-lived sub, but this is an extra thing to remember to do & clean up. I'd rather have the observable handle the subscription "smoothing"

Comment: Could you post that stream please? - It is almost impossible to give proper help without the full picture (of course you can alter the url ect..)

Comment: I would love to, but it's far too large to replicate here. Obviously if I could make the code cheaper to run or avoid the need to run it, that would be best, but that's beyond the scope of a stack overflow question, I think. I've added a micky-mouse example to try and illustrate the aim a bit better.

Comment: I've worked out a possible solution, don't know if it's great, but I'll add it as an answer....